# Does a general rule for forming Locative Singular exist?

Tags: locative, word-formation, singular

If I understood right the Locative is **mostly** to be formed **in singular** (e.g. domi, ruri, ...).
Some websites say that we **just** use the same form as **the genitive**, some websites say that we use the **genitive** in **1st and 2nd** declension and the **ablative** in **3rd** declension.

That fits if we look at humus (humi, **genitive**), bellum (belli, **genitive**) and also cities like Carthago (Carthagine / Carthagini, **ablative**).

---

But then I was confused as I found locatives like ruri (dative), tempori (dative) and luci (dative).
**What about them?**

Comment: The general rule is that the locative is formed like the locative. It's a separate (if moribund) case, not a series of special uses of the more common cases.

Comment: So there is no real regularity for those few Locatives that are left?

Comment: Sihler (276.6) says that *ruri* was made on analogy. I imagine a similar thing is going on with *tempori*, because *tempore* also works. Sometimes sound changes can be irregular.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer And regarding all city names? There are many cities and I suppose there is not a story or history behind every single locative, right? I wonder if there's any regularity.

Comment: Which ones are irregular? Not Romae, Athenis, or Carthagine?

Comment: I don't know. So every locative of a city is regular?

Comment: @Cyb3rKo As far as I know, yes, but if there is an irregularity, it doesn't necessarily go back to a proto-language.

Comment: Wikipedia has a good explanation of most of the issues here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locative_case#Latin

Comment: The rule of thumb I was taught is that for *regular* nouns (not, e.g., for *domus*) and adjectives, the  locative has the same form as the dative, with the exception of the singular 2nd declension, where it has the same form as the genitive. My experience has been that this rule works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

I was never taught that the locative was formed using another case, but I am aware many grammar books refer to a genitive-locative (or other cases) that is just an artefact used maybe as help to memorise it (but they add confusion to me).

As the locative is a case, survived in classic Latin for some words or expressions or turned into adverbs, it had its own ending to add to the stem which was *-i for the locative singular of all declensions and for all those words for which the locative would have made sense.

That explains why in classic Latin for first (with some phonetic modifications) and second declensions it looks like a genitive ("Romai > Romae, Corinthi"), for the third like a dative ("ruri") or ablative for those names that have the ablative in -i ("Neapoli"), fourth like a dative (but "domi" lost the stem), fifth probably like the genitive and dative ("diei" that became like the ablative "die" with the falls of -i), but also a different form "diu" (now adverb) is considered an old locative due to phonetic changes and the etymology of "dies".

Asa matter of completeness, the ending was *-ou (see "duou") for locative dual, *-su and *-oisu (*-oysu) for locative plural. I believe none of them can be ever seen in classic Latin as already absorbed by the ablative.

References:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locative_case
2. https://www.corsi.univr.it/documenti/OccorrenzaIns/matdid/matdid114728.pdf